# Apache Poi for Word - Create Custom style with TextAlignment

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

```
    private static void applyTextAlign(XWPFStyle style, TextAlignment value) {
        // Steps here
    }
```

How can I apply text alignment (of any sort, like TextAlignment.CENTER) to the style object being passed to the input of this function? I've been unable to find proper tutorials and examples on this.

```
        CTPPr ppr = style.getCTStyle().addNewPPr();
        CTTextAlignment textAlignment = ppr.addNewTextAlignment();
        STTextAlignment.Enum en = STTextAlignment.Enum.forInt(value.ordinal());
        textAlignment.setVal(en);
```

I tried something like the above, but naturally it's not correct and it even corrupts on docx. Other examples I've found here apply the text alignment directly to a paragraph, but I need the text alignment to be part of the style so it can be provided for any element, be it a paragraph or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the low level `CT*` classes is not as simple. Those classes are auto created from the `XML` schema. They do consider nothing. So one can not simply add a new `PPr` to the style. What if it has one already? It cannot have two because that would lead to a corrupt file. One has to check whether there is already a `PPr` and only if not, then add a new one. Same for `TextAlignment` in the `PPr` then.

But of course there are more problems because of the very experimental state of `XWPF` in `apache poi`. For example `XWPFStyle` is mostly made for reading only up to now. There are not much setters until now. And when using `CTStyle` one needs to check whether changes on this really were stored. For example the `java.util.List<XWPFStyle>` of `XWPFStyles` seems lost the contact to the single `CTStyle`s of the `XWPFStyle`s in it. So I had to use reflection to find a way to change the `CTStyle` so that the changes were stored.

Oh, and of course one can *not* be sure, that the ordinal of the `ST*` enumerations is the same as the one of the `apache poi` enumerations. That would be too simple, wouldn't it?

Following code works for me using current `apache poi 4.1.2`:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class CreateWordTextAlingmentStyles {

 private static XWPFStyle createNamedStyle(XWPFStyles styles, STStyleType.Enum styleType, String styleId) {
  if (styles == null || styleId == null) return null;
  XWPFStyle style = styles.getStyle(styleId);
  if (style == null) {
   CTStyle ctStyle = CTStyle.Factory.newInstance();
   ctStyle.addNewName().setVal(styleId);
   ctStyle.setCustomStyle(STOnOff.TRUE);
   style = new XWPFStyle(ctStyle, styles);
   style.setType(styleType);
   style.setStyleId(styleId);
   styles.addStyle(style);
  }
  return style;
 }

 private static void applyTextAlignment(XWPFStyle style, TextAlignment value) throws Exception {
  if (style == null || value == null) return;

  Field _ctStyles = XWPFStyles.class.getDeclaredField("ctStyles");
  _ctStyles.setAccessible(true);
  CTStyles ctStyles = (CTStyles)_ctStyles.get(style.getStyles());

  for (CTStyle ctStyle : ctStyles.getStyleList()) {
   if (ctStyle.getStyleId().equals(style.getStyleId())) {
    CTPPr ppr = ctStyle.getPPr(); 
    if (ppr == null) ppr = ctStyle.addNewPPr();
    CTTextAlignment ctTextAlignment = ppr.getTextAlignment(); 
    if (ctTextAlignment == null) ctTextAlignment = ppr.addNewTextAlignment();
    if (value == TextAlignment.AUTO) {
     ctTextAlignment.setVal(STTextAlignment.AUTO);
    } else if (value == TextAlignment.BASELINE) {
     ctTextAlignment.setVal(STTextAlignment.BASELINE);
    } else if (value == TextAlignment.BOTTOM) {
     ctTextAlignment.setVal(STTextAlignment.BOTTOM);
    } else if (value == TextAlignment.CENTER) {
     ctTextAlignment.setVal(STTextAlignment.CENTER);
    } else if (value == TextAlignment.TOP) {
     ctTextAlignment.setVal(STTextAlignment.TOP);
    }
    style.setStyle(ctStyle);
   }
  }
 }

 private static void applyJustification(XWPFStyle style, ParagraphAlignment value) throws Exception {
  if (style == null || value == null) return;

  Field _ctStyles = XWPFStyles.class.getDeclaredField("ctStyles");
  _ctStyles.setAccessible(true);
  CTStyles ctStyles = (CTStyles)_ctStyles.get(style.getStyles());

  for (CTStyle ctStyle : ctStyles.getStyleList()) {
   if (ctStyle.getStyleId().equals(style.getStyleId())) {
    CTPPr ppr = ctStyle.getPPr(); if (ppr == null) ppr = ctStyle.addNewPPr();
    CTJc jc = ppr.getJc(); if (jc == null) jc = ppr.addNewJc();
    if (value == ParagraphAlignment.BOTH) {
     jc.setVal(STJc.BOTH);
    } else if (value == ParagraphAlignment.CENTER) {
     jc.setVal(STJc.CENTER);
    } else if (value == ParagraphAlignment.DISTRIBUTE) {
     jc.setVal(STJc.DISTRIBUTE);
    } else if (value == ParagraphAlignment.HIGH_KASHIDA) {
     jc.setVal(STJc.HIGH_KASHIDA);
    } else if (value == ParagraphAlignment.LEFT) {
     jc.setVal(STJc.LEFT);
    } else if (value == ParagraphAlignment.LOW_KASHIDA) {
     jc.setVal(STJc.LOW_KASHIDA);
    } else if (value == ParagraphAlignment.MEDIUM_KASHIDA) {
     jc.setVal(STJc.MEDIUM_KASHIDA);
    } else if (value == ParagraphAlignment.NUM_TAB) {
     jc.setVal(STJc.NUM_TAB);
    } else if (value == ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT) {
     jc.setVal(STJc.RIGHT);
    } else if (value == ParagraphAlignment.THAI_DISTRIBUTE) {
     jc.setVal(STJc.THAI_DISTRIBUTE);
    }
    style.setStyle(ctStyle);
   }
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = null;
  XWPFRun run = null;

  XWPFStyles styles = document.createStyles();

  XWPFStyle style = createNamedStyle(styles, STStyleType.PARAGRAPH, "TextAlignmentAUTO");
  applyTextAlignment(style, TextAlignment.AUTO);
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setStyle(style.getStyleId());
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("TextAlignment.AUTO");
  run.setFontSize(8);
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Bigger text");
  run.setFontSize(30);

  style = createNamedStyle(styles, STStyleType.PARAGRAPH, "TextAlignmentBASELINECentered");
  applyJustification(style, ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
  applyTextAlignment(style, TextAlignment.BASELINE);
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setStyle(style.getStyleId());
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("TextAlignment.BASELINE");
  run.setFontSize(8);
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Bigger text");
  run.setFontSize(30);

  style = createNamedStyle(styles, STStyleType.PARAGRAPH, "TextAlignmentBOTTOMRight");
  applyJustification(style, ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
  applyTextAlignment(style, TextAlignment.BOTTOM);
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setStyle(style.getStyleId());
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("TextAlignment.BOTTOM");
  run.setFontSize(8);
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Bigger text");
  run.setFontSize(30);

  style = createNamedStyle(styles, STStyleType.PARAGRAPH, "TextAlignmentCENTERBoth");
  applyJustification(style, ParagraphAlignment.BOTH);
  applyTextAlignment(style, TextAlignment.CENTER);
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setStyle(style.getStyleId());
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("TextAlignment.CENTER");
  run.setFontSize(8);
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Bigger text");
  run.setFontSize(30);

  style = createNamedStyle(styles, STStyleType.PARAGRAPH, "TextAlignmentTOPLeft");
  applyJustification(style, ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
  applyTextAlignment(style, TextAlignment.TOP);
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setStyle(style.getStyleId());
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("TextAlignment.TOP");
  run.setFontSize(8);
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Bigger text");
  run.setFontSize(30);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordTextAlingmentStyles.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

It produces:

[image]